# Calculating Iadj for voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am attempting to control Vout to 3.8V and have selected [ADJ regulator](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317-n.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1617627692489) as my regulator.  According to the circuit below, I need to calculate what R1 and R2 should be to get the desired Vout, Vin being fixed at 5V.  Normally this wouldn't be a problem but the formula given below has the term Iadj and I am not sure how to calculate this?  I could calculate using Ohm's law if I knew the voltage of Adj pin, but I am not sure what this is.

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iadj should be given in the datasheet. It's the current that flows out of the adjustment pin, and is related to the quiescent current of the device.

[image]
(from page 8 of the datasheet you linked in the question)

However, with 5 volt input, you won't get a good 3.8 volts out of a 317; even at just 20 mA you'll need a voltage differential of at least 1.5 volts between input and output:

[image]
(page 9 of the same datasheet)

You need an LDO (low drop-out) regulator, which the 317 is not.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the datasheet-- use the typical number (50uA). Usually it will make little difference compared to resistor tolerances, especially if you're counting on the resistors to draw the minimum load current.

[image]

As others have mentioned, there isn't enough voltage for a LM317. Try a LM1117/[AMS1117](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) (quasi-LDO) or better, and be sure to carefully follow the recommendations for the output capacitor on any LDO regulator.

Answer (score 2):

The Iadj does not matter for two reasons.

First, if you use the recommended 240 ohm resistor between Vout and Adj pins, it will result into about 5mA of voltage divider current, so the 50uA typical current is so small that it can be just ignored in the calculations, as the difference is about 100 times.

Another reason is that you should not use LM317 to begin with, it cannot reliably regulate a 5V input to 3.8V output, as the difference is too small.